# NEON assembly fail to build for iOS in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, neon

I have a code base which compiles fine in all other NEON compilers, ndk-build, RVDS, etc, but under Xcode I get the error "bad instruction" for every NEON instruction I call. It basically seems like NEON is not detected.

I am attempting to build a static library, I went to New Project, selected Cocoa Touch Static Library, then added my existing files.

Everything I'm reading indicates that NEON should be already enabled. I removed all references to armv6, and am targeting iOS 5.1

Also the code in question is all contained as routines defined in ".s" files -- pure assembly. I am not using the intrinsics method calls.

It seems like the compiler is barfing on the whole file...

```
Unknown pseudo-op: .cpu
```

It lists all of the other settings, like .fpu, etc

Here are my current settings:

[image: Basic Compiler]
<sub>(source: [wasteonline.net](http://yano.wasteonline.net/stackoverflow/xcode_neon/basic_compiler.png))</sub>

[image: LLVM Code Gen]
<sub>(source: [wasteonline.net](http://yano.wasteonline.net/stackoverflow/xcode_neon/llvm_code_gen.png))</sub>

[image: LLVM Language]
<sub>(source: [wasteonline.net](http://yano.wasteonline.net/stackoverflow/xcode_neon/llvm_language.png))</sub>

Comment: Maybe your code is being compiled as thumb? Try adding "-mno-thumb" to  "Other C Flags".

Comment: Are you sure you're building this for the device, and not the i386-based Simulator?

Comment: I tried the -mno-thumb, no difference.

Comment: @BradLarson how do I guarantee I'm building for the device -- can you look at my settings?

Comment: @yano - In the schemes dropdown in the upper left hand corner of Xcode, does it say iOS Device next to your project name or iPhone or iPad Simulator? If the latter, switch that to the device.

Comment: @BradLarson it shows the name of the iPod touch that is plugged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the as tool I mentioned in my last answer turned out to be choking on my syntax as well, I realized there must be something else going on.

I followed the guidelines on the bottom of this post http://www.shervinemami.info/armAssembly.html#template

The changes I needed to make were:

1. converted my instructions to all lower case
2. use the naming directives to be compatible with mach-o (solved linker problems)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use GCC4.2. I solved a very similar problem switching to the old, good GCC.

In Build Settings -> Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C, select GCC

Actually, if you check the LLVM ARM status page, you'll see that it cannot yet parse .S files.

Comment: switching to GCC did not change anything, but your hint about LLVM not parsing .S set me down the right path... answer below